# Anyone know Docusign can inform us by sending the email if the recipient's email is wrong?

Tags: docusignapi

Does anyone have an idea how sender can get an email notification if the recipient's emailaddress is wrong(or status of envelop is autoresponded)?

We are using the docusign api for sending the envelop.

Thanks in advance.

Ankit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Larry explained if DocuSign receives hardbounce from the recipient's email server then DocuSign will be able to mark that recipient status as `"AutoResponded"` or `"Delivery Failure"`, and Sender will get email notification if correct setting is configured under Sender's `My Preference` as shown in below snapshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a status of "autoresponded" that DocuSign can detect in many cases. It is available via Connect / eventNotification or via polling for the envelope's status.

With the internet email system being the way it is, not every failure case can be detected. For example, if the email recipient only sees emails that are on their personal "white list" of senders, then that probably won't work out.

A bad email address that is simply swallowed (black hole) by a mail system will also be problematic. As the sender, you can detect that the envelope wasn't signed, but you can't always be sure why it wasn't.